received value must be a mock or spy function
I'd like to check if the login endpoint occurs after the submit button is clicked, but I don't know how I can "lockdown" the login function
test('Submitting the form with wrong username', async () => {
        const { result } = renderHook(() => authApiSlice.endpoints.login.useMutation(), { wrapper: AllTheProviders })
        const { getByTestId, findByRole, findByText } = render(
            <Form />
        )
        await act(() => {
            fireEvent.input(getByTestId('usernameField'), {
                target: {
                    value: 'example'
                }
            })

            fireEvent.input(getByTestId('passwordField'), {
                target: {
                    value: '1212'
                }
            })

            fireEvent.submit(getByTestId('submitBtn'))
        })
        expect(await findByText(/username or password is incorrect/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
        expect(getByTestId('usernameField')).toHaveValue('')
        expect(getByTestId('passwordField')).toHaveValue('')
    })

import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material'
import { store } from '../store/store'
import { theme } from '../theme/theme'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


export const AllTheProviders = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <CssBaseline />
          {children}
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ThemeProvider>
      <ToastContainer />
    </Provider>
  )
}

const customRender = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>,
) => render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options })

export * from '@testing-library/react'
export { customRender as render }

import { IChangeTaskReq, ICreateTaskReq, ITask, IToken, IUser, IUserReq } from "../../types/types";
import { authApi } from "./auth-api";

export const authApiSlice = authApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder => ({
        login: builder.mutation<IToken, IUserReq>({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: `auth/login`,
                method: 'POST',
                body
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Token', 'Tasks']
        }),
    })
})


export const { useLoginMutation } = authApiSlice

I want to check my login endpoint will be it called or not but i do not know how to mock my RTKQ endpoint. IDK i need test it here or not, i would be glad of help

I think you are misunderstanding what a unit test is. If you are testing the Form component submit handler then you should likely mock the API any handlers would be calling, e.g. mock the response value, and then assert on any UI changes in the Form component you are testing. The test I see renders a hook, and then separately renders a React component... the two are not connected in any way. You might also be able to mock the useLoginMutation hook and assert the mutation trigger was called with specific args.

In either case I think it's safe to assume if you trigger the endpoint that the API is called. It's not really your job to unit test the Redux-Toolkit code you don't own, let the Redux maintainers manage that.
